# AWS CDK How to handle Fn.getAtt that supposes to return list instead of string

Tags: aws-cdk

I have an AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint resource type and I want to get its DnsEntries values, which according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpcendpoint.html#aws-resource-ec2-vpcendpoint-return-values is a list of DNS entries. I want to be able to select the first item from the list so I tried something like this:

```
const vpcEndpoint = new ec2.CfnVPCEndpoint(this, "vpcendpoint", {
    serviceName: "com.amazonaws.vpce.us-west-2.vpce-svc-xxxxxx",
    vpcId: "vpc-123",
    privateDnsEnabled: false,
    subnetIds: ["subnet-123"],
    vpcEndpointType: "Interface",
});
const fisrtDnsEntry = cdk.Fn.select(0, cdk.Fn.getAtt(vpcEndpoint.logicalId, "DnsEntries"))
```

Which doesn't work since `Fn.select` expects an array of string but `Fn.getAtt` returns `IResolvable` and only has `toString()` method.

Any idea what else I can do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an open issue about this - https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3627.

Currently, you can use the following code snippet:

```js
const firstEntry = cdk.Fn.select(0, vpcEndpoint.attrDnsEntries);
const entryParts = cdk.Fn.split(':', firstEntry);
const primaryDNSName = cdk.Fn.select(1, entryParts);

new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'primaryDNSName', { value: primaryDNSName });
```

**CDK Output:**

[image]

**UI Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure that GetAtt will return a list, you just need to convince TypeScript that it's safe. You can do that using `core.Token.asList()`:

```
const firstDnsEntry = cdk.Fn.select(
  0,
  core.Token.asList(
    cdk.Fn.getAtt(vpcEndpoint.logicalId, "DnsEntries")
  )
)
```

Originally discovered this trick in this issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/8284